# Do I need to git add again after further changes?

Tags: git

Suppose I change a file in a Git repo:

```sh
echo 'Hello, world. ' > foo.txt
```

Then `git add` the changes:

```sh
git add foo.txt
```

Then change it again:

```sh
echo 'Goodbye, world. ' > foo.txt
```

Then `git commit`:

```sh
git commit -m 'Changed foo.txt'
```

Will Git take the latest version of `foo.txt` (`"Goodbye, world. "`) or the version that was added (`"Hello, world. "`)?

Comment: Yes, you have to re-add each time you make new changes. In your example, the second change (`Goodbye, world`) won't be in your commit. As a sidenote, this is a question that's quicker to test out than to ask, in my humble opinion :-)

Comment: As annoying as it is, yes, you will need to. Use `git add -u` for re-adding only modified files.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I wouldn't call it annoying, but I think it's important to know how this works to not miss changes

Comment: I meant annoying as in its a *pain*, it makes sense for it to be the way it is (not like it could be otherwise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `git add` each time you want to promote the changes on a file in your working directory to the stage.  If you stage a certain file, and then make further changes in the working directory copy, then commit, the staged version of the file is what would appear in the commit.

In fact, one reason the stage was created was for capturing a snapshot of your work which you intend to commit.  You may stage your work at some point, and then try a few things out in the working directory, without having any effect on what is in the stage.